# Is there anywhere in Harry Potter where we see his perspective on events many years later?

Tags: harry-potter

In Philosopher's Stone:

> In years to come, Harry would never quite remember how he had managed to
> get through his exams when he half expected Voldemort to come bursting
> through the door at any moment.

I find this quote interesting, because we see Harry's perspective of events many years later. Generally, Harry Potter is written from a third-person limited perspective, as a video camera on Harry's shoulder. Over here, we have a seemingly overhead view where we know Harry's thoughts many years later.

Does anything else like this appear in the seven books? Do we ever see Harry's perspective as an adult or older than the time of the events taken place?

(I am not including the epilogue in this question).

Comment: Seven books.... so Cursed Child doesn't count? Not that I know if what you are looking for would be in there anyway...

Comment: @Skooba of course Cursed Child doesn't count.

Comment: I think this is likely just a weird quirk in the first book as Rowling had still not completely settled down the voice of the series. But I would also be curious to see if anyone finds any other passages.

Comment: It would be unlikely, especially in the later books, because then the reader would know that Harry survives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excluding the epilogue (e.g. 9 years after Voldemort's defeat), this appears to be the sole occasion that the omniscient narrator projects Harry forward into the future to any significant extent.

You may wish to note that...

> "*In years to come*"

...isn't necessarily spoiler for the outcome of the remaining novels because this could (theoretically) describe the events of everything from *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban* onward.

Answer (score -1):

I've managed to find another occasion where this happens.

In *Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone* chapter 2, when Harry is in the zoo with the Dursleys and having a decent time (before he releases the Boa constrictor), we get Harry's future perspective:

> . . . and when Dudley had a tantrum because his knickerbocker glory
> didn't have enough ice cream on top, Uncle Vernon bought him another
> one and Harry was allowed to finish the first.
>
> **Harry felt, afterward, that he should have known it was all too good
> to last.**

I'll edit the answer if I find any other occasions.

Comment: I fail to see how this is "*many years later*". We seem to be getting his perspective a few minutes later, at most.

Comment: @Valorum- the question didn't specify only occasions the happened many years later: "Do we ever see Harry's perspective as an adult or older than the time of the events taken place?" Harry's perspective here is clearly after things started going badly with the Boa constrictor and him being punished by the Dursleys- Much more than a few minutes later, and fitting the question's requirement

Comment: "*Is there anywhere in Harry Potter where we see his perspective on events **many years later?**"*. It says it right there in the banner headline